# Find decomposition of $x^8 -1$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$, $\mathbb{F}_3$ and $\mathbb{F}_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

Let us consider $x^8 -1$. I want to decompose it over $\mathbb{F}_2$, $\mathbb{F}_3$ and $\mathbb{F}_4$.

- In $\mathbb{F}_3$ I have no problem, since I can use the cyclotomic cosets.
- In $\mathbb{F}_2$, I have $$ (\star)\quad \quad (x^8 -  1)= (x^4 - 1) (x^4 +1) = (x^2 - 1)(x^2 + 1)(x^4 +1) = ... = (x-1)^8$$

so the splitting field is $\mathbb{F}_2$ itself and the decomposition is the above one.

- Now, about $\mathbb{F}_4$, I have that $\mathbb{F}_4$ is an extension of $\mathbb{F}_2$ and therefore it contains its splitting field and therefore the decomposition is again $\star$.

Is the points for $\mathbb{F}_3, \mathbb{F}_4$ okay?

Comment: You are right in $\Bbb F_2$ and $\Bbb F_4$. Whether you are right for $\Bbb F_3$ depends on details you haven't given.

Comment: you must have a typo in (*) since the degrees of $x$ do not agree when added up

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I edited it. So this happens when $(n,q)$ are not coprime, right?

Comment: Because  $9=3^2$ the general result is that over $\Bbb{F}_3$ the polynomial $x^9-x=x(x^8-1)$ is the product of all the irreducible (monic) linear and quadratic polynomials. A count of degrees reveals that there must be three quadratic factors. You can find those by observing that $f(x)=x^2+1$ has no zeros in $\Bbb{F}_3$. Therefore the same applies to $f(x+1)$ and $f(x+2)$.